# heroku config:set SERVER_URL='https://secret-shore-88463.herokuapp.com' returns errors on CLI

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, command-line-interface

I created an app on Heroku CLI but when configuring, the command `heroku config:set SERVER_URL='https://secret-shore-88463.herokuapp.com'`
returns the errors below.

```
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the app name, something like:

```
heroku config:set SERVER_URL='https://secret-shore-88463.herokuapp.com' --app the_app_name_here
```